# iOS Register for .p12 file types (cfbundledocumenttypes)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I want to read on my app a .p12 file that will be sent to users email.

But the option "open in" does not appear for .p12 files.

I tried public.data and I can see the "open in" option in all files(I tried images, pdf, html files) except for .p12 files.

Why can't I see the "open in" option for .p12 files?

Comment: I just tried my own test. I emailed myself a p12 file. The Mail app does not show the "open in" menu for the file. They do this for images too. It's very annoying. Apple seems to think that no one would every want to use another app for images or p12 files. File an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @rmaddy With public.data I can get the "open in" on images. (I'm using an .jpg and ios simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is not possible to add the "open in" option for .p12 files.

I just changed the .p12 to my custom extension and my app can read the file.

I followed this tutorial: [How do I get my application to show up in the "Open in..." menu on iOS for a specific document type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1587/_index.html)